# HeUpdating the config items with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

the question I have is it possible to edit the config values in a custom config file within codeigniter?

I understand that

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

Would set a certain config item to a certain value, however would this change be permanent? If I have an admin config file for a website and want to allow the user to edit certain values that would need to be changed forever, or until the user changes them again.

Or am I better off storing the settings in a database and then fetching them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way to save changes in CI config, except write changes directly in your config file.

So better use DB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a value to persist during the lifetime of an application and that you considered having the user modify an application configuration variable.

**PROBLEM**

No matter what level of scope you try to save this 'setting' to, whether it be Application or Server, you risk the chance of losing it on a server reboot.

**ANSWER**

If you truly want to keep this value, you need to save it in a database.  Aside from physically losing your database, the value will always be there.